# Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one MDIPrent Form that is my main form. Now I am logging out form Main_Form by clicking LogOut MenuStrip. In my code I have prevented duplicate instance. But I get this error. I have googled so much, tried so many things but error doesn't go away.
Below is code for Program.cs file:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        LoggedInUser = string.Empty;
        loginSuccess = false;
        String thisprocessname = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        if (Process.GetProcesses().Count(p => p.ProcessName == thisprocessname) > 1)
            return;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MyApplicationContext context = new MyApplicationContext();
        Application.Run(context);

    }
    public class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
    {
        private Login_Form lgFrm = new Login_Form();
        public MyApplicationContext()
        {
                try
                {
                    lgFrm.ShowDialog();
                    if (lgFrm.LogonSuccessful)
                    {
                        ////lgFrm.Close();
                        lgFrm.Dispose();
                        FormCollection frm = Application.OpenForms;
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (Form fc in frm)
                                fc.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex){}
                        Application.Run(new Main_Form());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
            }
        }
}
```

Below is the code for Login_Form

```
public bool LogonSuccessful
    {
        get
        {
            return Program.loginSuccess;
        }

        set
        {
            Program.loginSuccess = value;
        }
    }

    private void BtnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login_Form lgn = new Login_Form();
        Program.loginSuccess = true;
        this.Hide();
        Program.LoggedInUser = TxtBxUserName.Text;
    }
```

Below is for Main_Form

```
private void LogOutMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login_Form lgFrm = new Login_Form();
        lgFrm.LogonSuccessful = false;
        Program.loggedOut = true;
        Program.LoggedInUser = string.Empty;
        this.Close();
        ////FormCollection frm = Application.OpenForms;

        ////foreach (Form fc in frm)
        ////{
        ////    MessageBox.Show(fc.ToString());
        ////}

        Program.MyApplicationContext context = new Program.MyApplicationContext();
        Application.Run(context);
    }
```

I have used context, because I want to make Main_Form, the only OpenForm of application. Somewhere I got the idea of using the context.

Comment: create a new process instead of Application.Run(context);
this is not a great solution but i'll write a good if you tell me why you do Application.Run() in the first place

Comment: Should I create Process on logOut or instead of Application.Run()? And I generally do Application.Run() to start application.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive

Comment: instead of running another application of your context, why won't you just start the program again or call a new thread?

Comment: Edited code in Main_Form. I added this.Close();. Even the same error. Before edit Login_Form could open and I was able to enter ID and password but now the Login_Form doesn't open but flashed and the error appeared.

Comment: you are trying to logout from the app itself(mainform = mdiparent),or the mainform you are trying to log out is one children?...if its mdi then you are closing the app itself and after (trying to run) another,you should open the log form first and then with your boolean property and with dialog result close the form.

Answer (score 4):

Your exception is because you call `Application.Run(...)` inside another `Application.Run(...)`, modify as follow:

```
//MyApplicationContext constructor
public MyApplicationContext()
    {
            try
            {
                lgFrm.ShowDialog();
                if (lgFrm.LogonSuccessful)
                {
                    ////lgFrm.Close();
                    lgFrm.Dispose();
                    FormCollection frm = Application.OpenForms;
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (Form fc in frm)
                            fc.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){}
                    //Application.Run(new Main_Form());  <<<---- Remove this
                    MainForm = new Main_Form();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){}
            //Add the ThreadExit event handler here
            ThreadExit += (s,e) => {
              if(Program.loggedOut) {
                Program.MyApplicationContext ctxt = new Program.MyApplicationContext();
                Application.Run(ctxt);
              }
            };
       }
     }
 //
 private void LogOutMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Login_Form lgFrm = new Login_Form();
    lgFrm.LogonSuccessful = false;
    Program.loggedOut = true;
    Program.LoggedInUser = string.Empty;
    this.Close();  //I think you want to call Application.Restart() here?
                   //if so, you don't need the ThreadExit event handler added in the MyApplicationContext() constructor.   
 }
```

Comment: in Main() I call Application.Run(context); Runs fine. But when I try to logout, the error appears.

Comment: @DhavalR just because you have the line `Application.Run(context)` in the `LogOutMenuItem_Click`, why do you need it? just remove it, if you want to show some form, show it directly.

Comment: Application.Run() is also in Main(). Because I don't want to Login_Form remain opened after LoginSuccess. And LoginForm.ShowDialog() is in context (i.e. in Program.cs. see code in the question).

Comment: @DhavalR you are saying about `log-out`, why talk about `log-in` here? You can't run 2 message loops in an application.

Comment: The actual scenario is, 1.user started application. 2.he does his work. 3.now he wants to logout and he did. 4. and loginForm appeared again after closing the Main_Form i.e. MDIParrent Form and main form of my application. Now after all this, there should not a form in Application.OpenForms. So I used ApplicationContext. Now as you can see the LoginSuccess checking is not made from Login_Form but from Context. I know I can't run 2 msgLoops in an application that's why I want to close the application and start it again.

Comment: @DhavalR see my edit if it helps, it not I can't help you more with the current design of yours. You don't need more calls to `Application.Run` (except the default auto-generated by designer), to hide, show form, just treat it normally. `Application.Run` is used to create a message loop and we just need 1 in an application. If you want to restart your application call `Application.Restart()`.

Comment: Ok. This helped. But now on logging out, Login_Form just flashes and Main_Form opens.

Comment: @DhavalR try using `Application.Restart()` instead, somehow calling `Application.Run(...)` while the current application is still running can't work expectedly.

Comment: @DhavalR if you don't want to use `Application.Restart()` which is the quickest way for you (I think), you can see my edit and try.

Comment: It let me enter Login_Form. But when I click on Enter Button (to Login) the error appears.

Comment: @DhavalR At which line the error occurs? I think you'd better go for `Application.Restart()`.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem

the best way to solve this is Using

```
Application.Restart();
```

you should Use it when ever a User Log out , so the main UI close

and the log in dialog appear !!

but with Log in Form U gotta use this

```
ControlBox = False;
```

so the User can't bypass it by closing it!!
Simply U can add an Exit Button with code

```
Application.Exit();
```

this is how i solved this problem with out any additional Usings or Errors ...

Answer (score 0):

try this: instead of firing a new application when logging off, just dispose your window and replace `MyApplicationContext()` in this:

```
    public MyApplicationContext()
    {
       bool isSuccessful = false;
       do
       {
            try
            {
                lgFrm = new Login_Form();
                lgFrm.ShowDialog();
                if (lgFrm.LogonSuccessful)
                {
                    isSuccessful = lgFrm.LogonSuccessful;
                    ////lgFrm.Close();
                    lgFrm.Dispose();
                    FormCollection frm = Application.OpenForms;
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (Form fc in frm)
                            fc.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){}
                    Application.Run(new Main_Form());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){}
        }while(isSuccessful);
    }
```

Comment: Same error appeared at same place. Login_Form just flashed and THE ERROR.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error cus' is just ran a program using this code and didn't got the error. did you removed the Application.Run(context); ?

Comment: I getting it at Application.Run(new Main_Form()); in MyApplicationContext.

Comment: @DhavalR try doing new Form1().ShowDialog(); instead